# Refresh repeater control within few seconds continuously

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

hi i am doing a social network service on asp.net c#.I want to refresh the messages within 1 second without loading whole page. I am display messages using repeater control.

I want to refresh this repeater control continuously after 1 second, but whole page should not be reloaded.

repeater control code

```
setInterval(function () { $(".refresh").load(location.href + " .refresh"); }, 1000);

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
 <ItemTemplate>




     <div style="border-top: thin none #BBCEB3; border-bottom: thin none #BBCEB3; padding: 10px;  width: 548px; margin-top: 10px; right: 10px; left: 10px; border-left-width: thin; margin-left: 15px; background-color: #e9eaee; border-left-color: #BBCEB3; border-right-color: #BBCEB3;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <div style="width: 58px; height: 40px">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="59px" ImageAlign="Top" ImageUrl="~/Profile/Image/Default.png" Width="55px" />
                        </div>
                    <div style="width: 307px;  margin-left: 65px; margin-top: -60px">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#000066"><%#Eval("SenderID") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="status" style=" width: 461px; margin-left: 78px; margin-top: 11px;">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Italic="False" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="Medium"><%#Eval("Messages") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;<div style="margin-left: 350px">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server"  Text="Posted on: " Font-Size="Small"><%#Eval("Time") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>




 </ItemTemplate>
```

textbox code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Message" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox3_TextChanged" style="margin-left: 12px; text-align: left;" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="564px" Height="100px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: simply use Update Panels or AJAX calls

Comment: put the whole `repeater` in the Update panel and set the `Update Mode` = `Always`

Comment: Don't do this in asp.net webforms. Firstly ASP.Net webforms isn't very good for ajax (which is updating the page without refreshing the whole page), not to mention you WILL kill your performance with viewstate. You need to learn javascript.

Comment: I cannot put whole repeater on update panel.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"   CodeBehind="Trans.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebClient.WebForm1" %>
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function () { $('#Repeater1').load(location.href + " #Repeater1"); }, 1000);
        });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
<ItemTemplate>


 <div style="border-top: thin none #BBCEB3; border-bottom: thin none #BBCEB3; padding: 10px;  width: 548px; margin-top: 10px; right: 10px; left: 10px; border-left-width: thin; margin-left: 15px; background-color: #e9eaee; border-left-color: #BBCEB3; border-right-color: #BBCEB3;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <br />
                <div style="width: 58px; height: 40px">
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="59px" ImageAlign="Top" ImageUrl="~/Profile/Image/Default.png" Width="55px" />
                    </div>
                <div style="width: 307px;  margin-left: 65px; margin-top: -60px">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#000066"><%#Eval("SenderID") %> </asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div id="status" style=" width: 461px; margin-left: 78px; margin-top: 11px;">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Italic="False" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="Medium"><%#Eval("Messages") %> </asp:Label>
                </div>
                &nbsp;<div style="margin-left: 350px">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server"  Text="Posted on: " Font-Size="Small"><%#Eval("Time") %> </asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>




</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: thanks dude, but my webform does not have head tag, because it  inherits from masterpage.  :(

Comment: could you give me a ajax code for refresh this. thanks